# How to call event parameter to another function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

My lambda handler is below

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    if event['params']['path'] == 'INSERT':
        return (test())

    else:
        return (test1())
```

I need to use the INSERT variable into inside another, here  test. if else need to add to another function which test1

```
def test():
     return 'hi'

def test1():
    event['params']['path'] == 'MODIFY':
    return 'hello'
```

Comment: Pass a parameter to `test1`, like `event`?

Comment: @AndrewLi can you write answer sir or good link also will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from @Andrew Li's comment:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    if event['params']['path'] == 'INSERT':
        return (test())

    else:
        return (test1(event['params']['path']))

def test1(insert_var):
    if insert_var == 'MODIFY':
        return 'hello'
```

But this could be made easier with a switch-like statement using a dictionary:

```
to_return = {'INSERT':'hi', 'MODIFY':'hello'}
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # return None by default
    return to_return.get(event['params']['path'], None)
```